# After adding a function to a stored procedure, the execution time is way too long

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like this.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[IBS_fetchreqVehicleinPodium]
   @locid integer=null
as
begin
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   SELECT  
       t.TBarcode, t.PlateNo, t.DelEcode
   FROM    
       transaction_tbl t
   WHERE   
       [status] IN (3,4) 
       AND locid = @locid 
       AND dtime >= getdate()-7 
       OR ([status] = 5 AND DATEDIFF(n, CAST(DelDate AS DATETIME), GETDATE()) <= 3 
           AND locid = @locid AND dtime >= getdate()-7)  
   ORDER BY  
       paydate
end
```

Also I want to check each `Tbarcode` status and calculate time difference, so I wrote a function like this:

```
ALTER function [dbo].[KRRTtime](@status numeric(18,2), @cardID VARCHAR(50)) 
RETURNS int
AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE 
     @requestedtime datetime,
     @currentdate datetime,
     @keyroomdate datetime,
     @krrttime int

   IF @status= 3 
   BEGIN
      SELECT @requestedtime = t.Paydate 
      FROM Transaction_tbl t 
      WHERE t.tbarcode = @cardID

      SELECT @currentdate = GETDATE()

      SELECT @krrttime = DATEDIFF(minute, @requestedtime, @currentdate)
   END

   IF @status = 4 OR @status = 5
   BEGIN
      SELECT @requestedtime = t.Paydate 
      FROM Transaction_tbl t 
      WHERE t.tbarcode = @cardID

      SELECT @keyroomdate = t.KeyRoomDate 
      FROM Transaction_tbl t 
      WHERE t.tbarcode = @cardID

      SELECT @krrttime = DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@requestedtime,@keyroomdate)
   END

   RETURN @krrttime
end
```

Then I called this function in my stored procedure.. after adding this function in my stored procedure... the execution time of the stored procedure taking long time

If I execute this stored procedure without function that s executing very fast..

Comment: Yes, hiding data access (`SELECT .. FROM ...`) inside a function is a sure-fire way to kill all your performance - don't do it! Can't you just add the `DATEDIFF(...)` directly to the query in your stored procedure?

Comment: so that time how i can check status of each tbarcode?

Comment: sir..could you please show once...how i can do this?

Comment: depend on the status i want to calculate time in minutes..that s why i wrote function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your database and you didn't post your exact table structure, either - but you could probably do something like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[IBS_fetchreqVehicleinPodium]
   @locid INTEGER = NULL
AS BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   -- I'd be careful with your GETDATE()-7 - what "7" does this subtract? 
   -- Days, months, years? I'd rather be explicit about it!
   DECLARE @TodayMinus7Days DATETIME

   -- assuming you mean "today minus 7 days" here .....
   SET @TodayMinus7Days = DATEDIFF(DAYS, -7, GETDATE())

   SELECT  
       t.TBarcode, t.PlateNo, t.DelEcode,
       -- use a CASE here - depending on the status, return one or the other DATEDIFF
       CASE
          WHEN [Status] = 3 
             THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.PayDate, GETDATE())
          WHEN [Status] IN (4, 5) 
             THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.PayDate, t.KeyRoomDate)
          -- just guessing here - if status is neither 3, 4, nor 5 - just return 0 in that case - ADAPT AS NEEDED!
          ELSE 0     
        END AS YourDateDiff  -- give it a meaningful column alias here
   FROM    
       dbo.Transaction_tbl t
   WHERE   
       ([status] IN (3,4) AND locid = @locid AND dtime >= @TodayMinus7Days)
       OR 
       ([status] = 5 AND DATEDIFF(n, CAST(DelDate AS DATETIME), GETDATE()) <= 3 AND locid = @locid AND dtime >= @TodayMinus7Days)
   ORDER BY  
       paydate
END
```

Comment: instead of this code: SET TodayMinus7Days = DATEDIFF(DAYS, -7, GETDATE()) i given:SET TodayMinus7Days = getdate()-7 ,,i want to filter last 7 days data..this is oke right?

Comment: @user3262364: as I said - I find the `GETDATE() - 7` to be unclear - you're removed 7 **what** - days? Months? Years? I prefer my way of being **clear** about what you're doing .....